# How to create JSON object with array of nested arrays for multiple days and multiple times?

Tags: json

I'm trying to create a JSON object file and I'm not sure how to document a list of all skating classes available. Currently I have the following:

```
[
{"classname":"FS1","classdays":["monday", "wednesday"]},
{"classname":"FS2","classdays":  ["tuesday", "thursday"]}
]
```

It works, the only problem is that each class "classname", has multiple classtimes for each day "classdays". And I'm not sure how to add another array of times and associate them with the specific day for the specific classes and add that to my current JSON file to create that structure.

Here are the classes in non-programming language - for clarity:

```
Classname: FS1
Monday classes are 12:00PM and 2:00PM
Wednesday classes are 1:00PM and 3:00PM
Classname: FS2
Tuesday classes are 4:00PM and 6:00PM
Thursday classes are 2:00PM and 8:00PM
Classname: FS3
Monday classes are 2:00PM and 4:00PM
Thursday classes are 2:00PM and 8:00PM
```

I'm open to suggestions on how best to structure, or restructure if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just to point out JSON is not a "programming language" it's a data language. The difference being JSON, like XML doesn't *do* anything it just describes objects.

Second, I think the direction you're heading in is going to run you squarely into the realization that JSON is not relational.

Finally, here's how I would do it:

```
[
    { "classname":"FS1",
      "classdays":[
        { "classday":"Monday",
          "classtimes": ["12:00 PM", "2:00 PM"]
        }, 
        { "classday":"Wednesday",
          "classtimes": ["1:00 PM", "3:00 PM"]
        }
        ]
    },
    { "classname":"FS2",
      "classdays":[
        { "classday":"Tuesday",
          "classtimes": ["4:00 PM", "6:00 PM"]
        }, 
        { "classday":"Thursday",
          "classtimes": ["2:00 PM", "8:00 PM"]
        }
        ]
    },
    ... And so on.
]
```

Comment: Thanks this is even more helpful that you listed both classes as examples. With all the nesting going on it can get confusing quickly. I'm just getting started with JSON and AJAX and I'm guessing, maybe incorrectly, that these JSON objects would typically be created dynamically by a call to a database using something like PHP or Python, or C#. Is that correct? Any additional information about practical usage or industry standard usage would be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: You are correct in thinking this could be a response from an JSON AJAX web method. Since C#, and I assume PHP and Python, have JSON serializers and you are trying to write this by hand I thought perhaps you were hoping to use it as a database of sorts. Clearly not so ignore my warning about the fact that JSON isn't relational. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make each entry in `classdays` an object, with the day name and times as keys:

```
[
    {
        "classname": "FS1",
        "classdays": [
            {
                "day": "monday",
                "times": [
                    "12:00",
                    "14:00"
                ]
            },
            {
                "day": "tuesday",
                "times": [
                    "16:00",
                    "18:00"
                ]
            },
            ...more days here...
        ]
    },
    ...more classses here...
]
```

You *could* make `classdays` an object instead of an array, keyed by day name:

```
[
    {
        "classname": "FS1",
        "classdays": {
            "monday": [
                "12:00",
                "14:00"
            ],
            "tuesday": [
                "16:00",
                "18:00"
            ],
            ...more days here...
        }
    },
    ...more classes here...
]
```

...but then the days have no order. Of course, I expect your code's logic could know what order the days of the week come in, but I think I'd probably use the first structure.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. A lot of nesting required for these, but I guess that is what you need to do.

Comment: @M_66: No worries. Yeah, it looks worse than it is because I was formatting for maximum clarity. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
{"classname":"FS1","classdays":[{"day":"monday","times":["12:00PM","2:00PM"]},{"day":"wednesday","times":["1:00PM","3:00PM"]}]}
```